# Only show text when form is filled with in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

So i am trying to get the users bmi, which i am doing in this controller like so

```
$form = $this->createForm(CaloriesType::class);

    $bmi = 0;

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $form->getData();
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $bmi = ($data['mass'] /  ($data['height'] * $data['height'])) * 10000;

        switch ($bmi){
            case $bmi < 18.4:
                $bmi = "Underweight";
                break;
            case $bmi > 18.5 && $bmi < 24.9;
                $bmi = "Normal";
                break;
            case $bmi > 25 && $bmi < 29.9;
                $bmi = "Overweight";
                break;
            default:
                $bmi = "Obese";
                break;
        }
    }
```

then in my html i am trying to figure out a way to only show the text when the user has entered and send something since i dont want there just to be random text all of the time.

Here is what i tried.

```
{{ form_start(our_form) }}
{{ form_widget(our_form) }}
<div class="from-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" name="Send" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
</div>
{% if bmi == 0 %}

{% else %}
According to BMI you are:  {{ bmi }}
{% endif %}
{{ form_end(our_form) }}
```

It doesnt quite seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the default behaviour of [form_end](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables) is to render *unrendered* field also. If you want do disable this, you can do as follow:

```
{# don't render unrendered fields #}
{{ form_end(our_form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

`{% if bmi == 0 %}` doesn't seem to work, did you try

`{% if bmi != 0 %}
    According to BMI you are:  {{ bmi }}
{% endif %}`

or

`{% if bmi > 0 %}
    According to BMI you are:  {{ bmi }}
{% endif %}`?

When I have problems with if-clauses I use `{{ dump(bmi) }}` to check what is given to twig.